# SWT TableViewer Header-Height

Tags: java, winapi, swt

I'm changing the fontsize of a SWT Tableviewer, but the height of the table-headers doesn't change, and thus the label is being cut off. Is there any way to fix this?

(This is on Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Table` **Comes Under** `SWT`and on the other `TableViewer` **Comes Under** `JFace`. So it is not clear whether you need a solution for `TableViewer` or `Table`. Also in absence of any code snippet from your side, I am choosing to demonstrate it for `JFace` and `TableViewer`, though the concept will remain same for `Table` and `SWT`.

**>> Before Setting Font**

[image: Before]

**>> After Setting Font**

[image: After]

You can see the difference in header heights.

**>> Code**

```
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class TVHeaderTest 
{
    private class MyContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
            return (MyModel[])inputElement;
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
    }

    public class MyModel {
        public int counter;
        public MyModel(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Item " + this.counter;
        }
    }

    private static Display display;

    public TVHeaderTest(final Shell shell) 
    {
        final Table table = new Table (shell, SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.CHECK);
        table.setLinesVisible (true);
        table.setHeaderVisible (true);

        final String[] titles = {"!", "Description", "Resource", "In Folder", "Location"};
        for (int i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn (table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setText (titles [i]);
            column.setWidth(100);
        }

        final TableViewer v = new TableViewer(table);
        v.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
        v.setContentProvider(new MyContentProvider());


        MyModel[] model = createModel();
        v.setInput(model);
        v.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);


        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Set Font");

        // FOCUS ON THIS PART - START
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() 
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) 
            {
                FontDialog d = new FontDialog(shell);
                FontData data = d.open();
                table.setFont(new Font(display, data));
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    table.getColumn(i).pack();
                }

            }
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        // FOCUS ON THIS PART - END
        shell.pack();
    }

    private MyModel[] createModel() {
        MyModel[] elements = new MyModel[10];
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            elements[i] = new MyModel(i);
        }
        return elements;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        new TVHeaderTest(shell);
        shell.open ();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }

        display.dispose ();

    }

}
```

Checkout the code between `// FOCUS ON THIS PART - START` and `// FOCUS ON THIS PART - END`comments.

Also you can not do this for setting header image. See the [Table Header Image Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=41670)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes I meant TableViewer in JFace (I didn't know there is a difference between JFace and SWT). From what I can see your code does the same as mine, by using .setFont(). However on my machine (Windows XP) the height of the header remains the same. Also this happens when I run your code: http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=swttableviewerfzk5.png - Seems to be a windows issue. Any idea how I could work around or fix this?

Comment: @Dexter: Yes it seems like an OS related problem. As per the **Bug** link I have posted: `This is a platform limitation.  Windows won't grow the height of the header`. SWT is known to access the OS widget directly. So the windows limitation is extended to SWT. Although, the comment was posted in 2006 still my best guess is that it was for XP. As a work around have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktable/ and http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php.