# SWT Table Header Height with Image Cross Platform

Tags: java, image, swt

Java SWT Table

I added an image along with text for each column in my table.

The table displays perfectly on Windows and Linux, however on Mac Java does not use the image to resize the table header. Is there a work around or trick?

```
...
// Create the table columns.
TableViewer oTableViewer = new TableViewer(oSash, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
Table oTable = oTableViewer.getTable();
...
oTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
TableColumns[] oColumns = new TableColumn[3];
for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < oColumns.length; iColumn++)
    oColumns[iColumn] = new TableColumn(oTable, SWT.NONE);

...
Image imgCol1 = new Image(display, oStream);
Image imgCol2 = new Image(display, oStream);
Image imgCol3 = new Image(display, oStream);

// Set the column widths and names.
oColumns[0].setText("My 1st Column");
oColumns[0].setWidth(100);
oColumns[0].setImage(imgCol1);
oColumns[1].setText("My 2nd Column");
oColumns[1].setWidth(100);
oColumns[1].setImage(imgCol2);
oColumns[2].setText("My 3rd Column");
oColumns[2].setWidth(100);
oColumns[2].setImage(imgCol3);
```

I am using Eclipse Luna.

The Mac in question has the latest JDK installed, v8. I downloaded the JDK onto the Mac last week, so whatever was the latest and greatest 64-bit JDK last week.

Oh, I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806208/swt-tableviewer-header-height) question on Stackoverflow, but that did not talk of images, sadly.

Comment: +1 for your interesting question. cuz it seems it questions **write once and run everywhere** slogan

Comment: Java is ABSOLUTELY not write once and run everywhere. Want proof? Use setForeground() to set the foreground color of a group text box. The group text box will not display properly, displays black. A person wrote a bug against that in the Eclipse bug database. The response was "not a bug," because Java uses Windows themes and Windows controls, but did not override the colors, blah, blah, blah. Sadly, nobody continued the thought to say that Java uses the controls from the OS, and as such any bugs gets transferred. .Net by comparison does not suffer that. Other controls also have issues.

Comment: @KickButtowski I forgot to add that in my comment, out of space. Anyways, I also have issues with text box controls. Do not even get me started on the tree control. I am being punished there, because one cannot set the foreground, selected, or other colors. My hope of a color scheme to match Windows File Explorer is dashed, because tree controls look HORRIBLE on GNOME 3 (CENTOS 7). The list goes on, and on. I am hoping the Table SWT control has a trick. Yes, I do not "question", but take offense to the write once run anywhere, because it is not true, not yet.

Comment: clarification: in first comment "group text box" should be "Group".  I was not allowed to edit my comments, as over 5-minutes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use a JFace `TableViewer`, but then add the columns to the `Table` instead of the viewer?

Comment: @Baz Because I had myself as a teacher, talking companion, coach, and everything else. I found code on the Internet, most likely here on Stack Overflow, as I usually hang out here and search here, that implemented a table. I borrowed the concept and that was that. The goal originally is to mimic the Windows File Explorer, as I mentioned in a comment. Obviously, my source example was wrong, and I need to revisit what I did.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) is an excellent tutorial about `TableViewer`s.

Comment: I don't have Mac, hence only a guess (BTW a screenshot might help). Did you try to enlarge the table font, set the images and restore the font? Are the column images the first ones that are set? I remember a limitation of `TableItem`s is that the first image dictates the size for all images.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann You asked great questions. I will ask for a screenshot. Yes that would help. No: I did not try setting the table font, then set the headers, and then restoring the font. I did think of enlarging the font and using that to enlarge the table. That assumes that Tables enlarge on Mac.  Each column has the exact same image (more or less), either an up arrow or a down arrow, same height, though. I could reduce the size of the arrow too, but micro sized arrows look bad and hard to see. I will give it a try, though on the font. Great suggestion.